# Partitioning recommendations for installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on SSD/HDD

Tags: partitioning, software-installation

**Summary of Current System Information:**
Currently, the operating system has the following storage distribution, none is located in a separate hard disk partition, that is, everything is mounted in the same partition on both the SSD and HDD disk
**On SSD:**

- **Root (/):** 63 GB
- **/home (User):** 18 GB
- **/var (Variable Data):** 11 GB
- **/usr (System Programs):** 7.7 GB
- **/opt (Additional Packages):** 964 MB
- **/boot (System Boot):** 246 MB

**On HDD:**

- /home (User): 30 GB
  -/swap: 11 GB

**Ask:**
I am looking to partition my 150 GB SSD and 1 TB HDD to have ease of backup, security in the operating system, performance, considering that I am learning about databases in PostgreSQL, web development and cybersecurity. My hardware includes an 11th generation Core i5 processor and Intel Iris

**Goals:**

1. Ease of backup.
2. Security in the operating system.
3. Optimized performance.
4. Support for multiple virtual machines and dedicated directories for databases and backups.
5. Server deployment

The following proposal was made by the well-known ChatGPT based on the article: https://www.daniloaz.com/es/la-importancia-de-particionar-correctamente-un-disco-en-linux/
I don't really understand the rationale for partitioning the disk so much and I want to know your comments on this:

**Partitioning Proposal:**

- **SSD (150 GB):**

  - Root (/): 50 GB
  - /var (Variable Data): 20 GB
  - /usr (System Programs): 15 GB
  - /opt (Additional Packages): 10 GB
  - /boot (System Boot): 5 GB
  - /swap (Swap Area): 10 GB (equivalent to RAM for hibernation)
- **HDD (1TB):**

  - /home (User - Extended Storage): 400 GB (may be more depending on your needs)

This proposal seeks to balance data distribution, maximize performance on the SSD and take advantage of the HDD for extensive storage and backups. The swap partition on the SSD helps in hibernation situations.
Any additional tips to improve this proposal or specific considerations for my intended use?

Answer (score 1):

Keep complexity out of your setup.

It is totally not needed what you want to do; it was the method decades ago but that method is no longer used. We also ditched a swap partition years ago in favor of a swap file. No need for `/opt/`; just install 3rd party to your 2nd disk.

The cloud method is the most used versions nowadays and it is 2 disks:

- `/` on 1 physical disk prefer an SSD,
- all personal files on a 2nd physical disk, prefer a fairly quick HDD.

If you mount the 2nd one as `/u/` you symlink `/var/www/` to `/u/var/www` for your website and `/var/lib/mysql/` and `/var/log/` to `/u/var/lib/mysql` and `/u/var/log/`. `/u/` also holds all the changed settings you altered on `/` so you can copy/paste them as needed and you them also have an online backup in case of an emergency.

Your backup procedure then becomes:

- `/u/` daily using rsync incremental backup
- a full backup weekly.

Re-installing becomes easy too.

Want a new OS? Install it on a new SSD, replace the old one and copy your alterations over. If it does not work reinsert the old one and investigate the problems.. Need a new data disk? Install it and restore from your rsync backup. If it does not work reinsert the old one and investigate the problems.

Comment: I also like to keep /home inside / on SSD. That way all your user settings, mostly hidden,  which are used more than data are also quick. But keep all data normally in /home on HDD. If room on larger SSD, you can split data between SSD & HDD. But more partitions, become more to manage space. Trade off between more partitions and correct sizing and data in large partition.  Backup should really be to other drives/locations. I do a copy of data which now is only on SSD to HDD, but that is not a backup as it does not preserve old files or changed file history.

Comment: totally agree :)